# Underscore with count for duplicate values in angular json array

Tags: json, angularjs, count

Can anyone please tell me how to put count in duplicate values in angular JSON array:

My actual array is given below:

```
$scope.datas.resultsOrder =['Data1','Data2','Data3','Data3','Data4','Data4'];
```

in the above array `Data3` and `Data4` is repeating twice, so i need it to come as `Data3_1, Data3_2, Data4_1, Data4_2` order within that array like as shown below:

```
$scope.datas.resultsOrder =['Data1','Data2','Data3_1',      
'Data3_2','Data4_1','Data4_2'];
```

Also the values within that array are **dynamic values** and **not static**

Can anyone please tell me some solution for this?

Comment: So, you want to transform/compress your array into the 2nd form?

Comment: @DavinTryon yes.......

Comment: You will probably have to loop over the original array and the produce a new array in the 2nd form.  Have you tried that?  What do you have so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like UnderscoreJS for these kind of problems. In underscoreJS you can do something like this:

```
function uniq(array) {
    var grouped = _.groupBy(array);

    return _.reduce(grouped, function(result, x) {
        if(x.length > 1) {
            _.each(x, function(val, key) {
                result.push(val + '_' + (key + 1));
            });
        } else {
            result.push(x[0]);
        }

        return result;
    },[]);
}

uniq(['Data1','Data2','Data3','Data3','Data4','Data4']);
// ["Data1", "Data2", "Data3_1", "Data3_2", "Data4_1", "Data4_2"]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
function transform(arr) {
    var c = {};
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        var ar = arr[i];
        if(! (ar in c) ) {
            c[ar] = 0;
        }
        c[ar]++;
    }
    var res = []
    ;
    for(var d in c) {
        if(c.hasOwnProperty(d)) {
            var l = c[d]
            ;
            if(l === 1) {
                res.push(d);
                continue;
            }
            for(var i = 0; i < l; i++) {
                res.push(d + '_' + (i + 1));
            }
        }
    }
    return res;
}

$scope.datas.resultsOrder = transform(passTheArrayHere);
```

Note: No guarantee for order.